# Does git gets installed in IBM/AS400

Tags: php, git, unix, version-control, ibm-midrange

I have PHP on running on an AS400. Can Git be also be installed on an AS400? I'd like to use it to maintain version control.

Answer (score 7):

The YiPs site has instructions on how to get it running in PASE.  You can find it here:

http://youngiprofessionals.com/wiki/index.php/PASE/OpenSourceBinaries

Scroll to the middle of the page or search the page for "Git".

### UPDATE

I've since written [this article](http://bit.ly/mcpress-git-install) describing how to install Git on IBM i.

Answer (score 5):

A friend of mine wrote an unpublished article on installing Git on IBM i. I need to encourage him to publish it.

Comment: Yes he was, see my answer for the link to the article.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running git on my IBM i since over a year now. As Alan Seiden responded earlier, I've done an article about setting it up. I got it finished finally:

http://www.youngiprofessionals.com/wiki/index.php/PASE/Git

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is currently not a package that can be directly installed on the server.

However, it may be possible if you are willing to put in the work to get it to run in PASE (which is the unix equivalent in iOS/5).

Answer (score 0):

You will need an AIX version to run in PASE (qsh).  I do not believe this to be an officially supported platform for git (somehow those who REALLY like git, do not happen to work with IBM system with an entrance fee).

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking to do change control on with git?

Just the PHP source ... or native code as well?

I know that Subversion has been ported to IBM i quite successfully.

For native code, however, I wouldn't suggest an IFS based source control system ... you want to go with a system that's designed to handle native source & objects.

Comment: The chief issue with native source (ex. QxxxSRC files) would be that each source record is prefixed by 12 bytes of line sequence and date changed.  This might seem superfluous to git fans, since the change date (commit date) may be more accurately tracked by git-blame.

Comment: Actually, there's a whole lot more involved in REAL change control on IBM i ... managing the source is just one part of it.  Reconstructing objects correctly, modifying databases without loosing data, ensuring that changes can be put in place without failing midstream due to locked objects, remote deployment, etc.

Comment: git is intended as a Source Version Control System [SVCS] for development.  Object deployment is another issue, though obviously there can be a relationship between the two. Perhaps we should build an open source deployment tool for IBM i.

Comment: @WarrenT a lot of years ago I wrote Itaka (iSereis Tool Kit, but in honor to Cavafy's poem :) with precompile options for sources, new soruces LNKPGM & LNKSRV to make *PGM & *SRVPGM, assign sources to an issue or IT request, and move the "issue fix" from the develop machine to test, and from test to production machine executing instructions before restore objectes and after do it... as memories :) I would donate the code to an OpenSource project if there are interest for it :)

Comment: @david git essentially just manage an IFS file system.  All the rest must be done by something else (like maven in the Java world).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen correct ... my point was, if you're going to try and manage RPG, CL, or Cobol source, you should use a tool that understands how to manage them.

Comment: When I say "manage an IFS file system" I mean that git is responsible for ensuring that the flat files present on disk are corresponding to the given commit.  Nothing more.  Anything else but creating and deleting flat files with a given content is outside the scope of git.  This automatically means that anything that requires invocation of as/400 commands to get to their correct state is not well suited for git.  It could probably be taught but i do not think it will work well.

Comment: To my understanding sources would be better handled by a tool suitable for handling database table content.